# QTableview Search

Tags: c++, qt, search, qt5

I am doing a search engine for a QTableview, and this is what i have until now:

```
  void Inventory::on_Search_clicked(){

    QModelIndexList matchList = ui->tableView->model()->match(ui->tableView->model()->index(0,0), Qt::EditRole, ui->lineEdit->text(), -1,  Qt::MatchFlags(Qt::MatchContains|Qt::MatchWrap));

    if(matchList.count()>=1){

            ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(matchList.first());
            ui->tableView->scrollTo(matchList.first()); 
            }

    QSound::play("/home/adan/Groostore/Resources/Sounds/Update.wav");
}
```

It works as required, but i want to add another functionality:

This code search for specific matches with a QLineedit and it selects and scrolls to the first value of the QModelindexList, but, if i click a second time searching the same text on the QLineedit, i would like the selection to scroll to the 2 item on the QModelindexList, i have tried many things with no luck, i hope you can help on this, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an index that indicates the number of occurrence that must be selected:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):QWidget(parent){
        lineedit = new QLineEdit;
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Search");
        view = new QTableView;
        model = new QStandardItemModel;
        view->setModel(model);

        QGridLayout *lay = new QGridLayout(this);
        lay->addWidget(lineedit, 0, 0);
        lay->addWidget(button, 0, 1);
        lay->addWidget(view, 1, 0, 1, 2);

        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::onClicked);
        connect(lineedit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &Widget::onTextChanged);

        // fill model
        const QStringList words = {"stack", "overflow"};
        model->setColumnCount(2);
        for(int i=0; i < 20; i++){
            int p = QRandomGenerator::global()->bounded(words.length());
            model->appendRow(new QStandardItem(words[p]));
        }
    }
    void onClicked(){
        findText(lineedit->text(), ++index, Qt::MatchContains|Qt::MatchWrap);
    }
    void onTextChanged(){
        index = -1;
    }
    void findText(const QString & text, int from, Qt::MatchFlags flags = Qt::MatchFlags(Qt::MatchStartsWith|Qt::MatchWrap)){
        if(text.isEmpty())
            return;
        QModelIndexList indexes = model->match(model->index(0,0),
                                               Qt::EditRole,
                                               text,
                                               -1,
                                               flags);
        if(indexes.length() > from){
            QModelIndex ix = indexes.at(from);
            view->setCurrentIndex(ix);
            view->scrollTo(ix);
        }
    }
    int index = -1;
    QStandardItemModel *model;
    QTableView *view;
    QLineEdit *lineedit;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Let me work on understanding that code, if i manage to do it, i'll buy a coffee, or 2.

Comment: @AdanRH `Qt::MatchContains` searches if the text contains the text, in the case of `Qt::MatchStartsWith` it searches if the text starts with the text. Isn't the name of the flags clear?

Comment: Yes it know the flags behavior, the thing is that on the definition of the findText function, you have Qt::MatchStartsWith, and when you call the function you are using Qt::MatchContains, sorry, so on the function is just for pure definition? Thanks

Comment: @AdanRH I only copy the default flags of QAbstractItemModel::match to keep the convention, yes, they are only definition.

Comment: I think i have understood the code, but i might have not explained myself correctly on my statement, sorry again for that... i meant that if i keep clicking the search button it will keep on going, first click = first index, second click = second index, and keep on going on the search until we reach the last index :C

Comment: @AdanRH I don't understand you, what I understood from your question is: Let's assume that the first column shows ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"] then if the user writes "A" and press the button then you must select the first item, then if the user presses the button again without changing the text then the selected item must be the third, and if you press returned the selected item must be the fourth. I am right? If I am not, then explain what you want with a practical example like the one I indicated.

Comment: I was confused because i am just reading the code as i don't have my computer with me now, your example  ["A", "B", "A", "A", "B"] is exactly what i was looking for Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207319/discussion-between-adan-rh-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: It worked perfectly, the main logic on it is the int from, which one is being incremented as you click on search. Thanks!